# Using a generator to insert a new row into a Firebird Database

Tags: asp.net, firebird, firebird2.5

There is a way to insert a new row into a Firebird database using a generator, but for purposes of this project I should not use triggers to get the next ID for the table where I want to insert.

I'm using Entity Framework for Firebird in a .NET MVC project. What could I do to guarantee inserted new rows do not have duplicate primary keys or another conflict?

It's important to mention that I want to control this situation from a controller or method.

Comment: Why should you not use a trigger, what kind of arbitrary restriction is that?Are you restricted to Firebird 2.5? If you can use Firebird 3, you could use the [identity column](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity) (`generated by default as identity`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key defined, then it is not possible to have duplicate primary keys (but attempts to insert a row with an id that already exists will yield an error).

If you really are not allowed to use a trigger (which to be honest sounds like a rather arbitrary and counterproductive requirement), you can create a sequence (aka generator), and generate the id in your insert statement using the [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-nxtvlufor) expression.

So, create a sequence (one for each table):

```sql
create sequence sq_mytable;
```

And use it on insert:

```sql
insert into mytable (id, column1, column2) 
  values (next value for sq_mytable, 'value1', 'value2');
```

Comment: You are right, it's an arbitrary and counterproductive requirement. But it's what we got. I will try your solution, but first I need to adapt it to use with Linq.

Comment: @Klezk To be honest, I'm not sure if you can get that to work with Linq. Using a trigger would be the far easier solution to this problem (or upgrading to Firebird 3 and using an identity column).

Comment: @Klezk can you also use `INSERT ... VALUES ... RETURNING id` clause to receive that new ID value into the query object, if Linq allows returning data from inserts ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Unfortunately, we can't upgrade to Firebird 3 because it's an integration what we are developing into an existing Database. Directly with Linq it's imposible, but I'm using raw queries with Entity Framework for Firebird. I'm still on it.

Comment: @Arioch'The No, only if you are using EF after insert into a new instance class table.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm using the statement for the sequence you suggested to me, but I have the next inconvinient. For example, the last ids inserted into the table that already exist are **938575382, 938681792, 938749253**. After insert the new row using `next value for sq_mytable`, the new id is **1751**. I'm missing something?. May be this is a stupid question, but I want to be sure that there is a way to do it.

Comment: @Klezk What I suggested assumes that you always use the sequence for generating ids (and that only one sequence is used for a table). Either there are two sequences in use for the table, or another method for generating ids is used elsewhere, or - if you previously used a different method for generating ids - you need to initialize the sequence at the desired start id (using [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence-alter))